# C++ Builder - Indy - Receiving certified emails

Tags: email, c++builder, indy10, indy-9

i'm using C++ builder 6 and Indy 9/10.
I'm coding to receive certified emails with attachments (basically pdf and xml files).
When i receive the email, it have a TidMessageParts with one multipart/mixed part and others parts for a small text, an xml attachment with info about the certification of the email and parts for digital signature and more.
My problem is: how to open the first part (multipart/mixed) to extract text and attachment in it.

See the answer i'll post.

Thank you.
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

`TIdMessagePart` is a `TCollectionItem` descendant.  The `TCollectionItem::Collection` property points to the **owning** (parent) `TCollection`, not to some inner collection, like you are expecting <sup>1</sup>. That is why `mp1` and `mp` are pointing at the same address in memory.

You don't "open a message part" in Indy.  You simply iterate the `TIdMessage::MessageParts` collection from one end to the other until you find the particular part you are interested in, such as by looking at their class type, `ContentType` properties, etc. For example:

```
TIdMessageParts *mp = MailMessage->MessageParts; 

for (int i = mp->Count-1; i > 0; --i)
{
    TIdMessagePart *part = mp->Items[i];

    if ((TIdAttachment *att = dynamic_cast<TIdAttachment*>(part)) != NULL)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if ((TIdText *txt = dynamic_cast<TIdText*>(part)) != NULL)
    {
        if (txt->ContentType = "text/xml")
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (txt->ContentType = "text/plain")
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>1: support for inner nested collections has [not been implemented yet](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/139), not even in Indy 10. It won't be implemented until Indy 12 at the earliest.</sup>

Comment: Inspetting the classname of the two first parts i have seen they are TIdText parts so i inspected them:

Part #: 0 - ClassName: TIdText
ContentType: multipart/mixed; boundary="----------=_1540469045-26964-21506"

Part #: 1 - ClassName: TIdText
ContentType: multipart/alternative; boundary="----------=_1540469045-26964-21507"

Part #: 2 - ClassName: TIdText
ContentType: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Correct test and parts 3 to the end are correct.

Parts #0 #1 body properties are empty. They have boundaries so contents are present. A solution to extract the data i need? Thanks

Comment: I already gave you the solution in my answer. You can simply ignore the two `multipart/...` parts while iterating the collection. They are *supposed* to have empty bodies. Note that Indy 9 really does NOT handle MIME very well, especially multiple levels of nesting. Indy 10 does a better job at that (it has a TIdMessagePart::ParentPart` to handle nesting - Indy 12 will (hopefully) do an even better job of handling nesting). You really shouldn't be using Indy 9 anyway, it is very outdated by modern standards. Is there a reason why you have not upgraded to Indy 10 yet? It still supports BCB6.

Comment: I can't ignore them because the contents i need are in these parts and scanning all parts i can't find them. I haven't upgraded as v 9 has the funciontions i have needed until now. Thanks for answer Remy.

Comment: @Fabrizio yes, you can ignore the `multipart` parts, because Indy parses them by creating a collection item for each `multipart` header set, but does not store their *content* in the same collection items. The *content* is parsed and separated into additional collection items as needed. And v10 has everything that v9 has, but it also supports things that v9 doesn't, like Unicode, and *adequate* MIME handling especially for multi-level nesting of parts. v9 simply can't handle modern emails that are beyond the simplest of complexity. v10 can handle them better. You really should upgrade.

Comment: i have tested with indy 10 but the result is the same. A suspect: in a part of the email there is written: 'this is an s/mime email" But does indy manage s/mime email? I suspect NO, so in wich manner i can read and import data from a such email? Thank You, Fabrizio

Comment: @Fabrizio "*i have tested with indy 10 but the result is the same*" - then please edit your question to show an actual email that is not parsing the way you expect, and show what the resulting `MessageParts` output actually looks like. "*does indy manage s/mime email*" - Indy will not decrypt an S/MIME email, no. But it will still parse and separate any unencrypted MIME parts, at least.  And then you can decrypt the encrypted parts manually as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem i posted:
@Remy told me a right observation i was unable to understand well:  *"The content is parsed and separated into additional collection items as needed."* 
The email i'm reading is a 'certified email' so the **real email** is the attachment with .eml extension that indy where reading and i ignored (my email client shows the attachments in the contained email joined with the attachments of the base email).
So, when i have right understood the Remy words and realized *where* to search the attachments:

1. i have estracted the .eml file to a folder
2. added a new TIdMessage component on the form (called PartMessage);
3. used LoadFromFile method to read the stored file
   and now in PartMessage all attachments are visible and i was able to save them as files.

Thanks again to Remy as his words that where preciouses to reach the solution.

P.S. The solution works fine for Indy 9 and 10 with necessary adjustments due to different versions.
P.P.S. i don't know why during my tests i found the text that the email was s/mime encoded as it is not.